# UITabBar Border and Shadow issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I need to put shadow effect in `UITabBar`, which I'm getting by following code:

```
tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
```

[image]

And it is working perfectly.

But, I need to remove the border on top of the `UITabBar`, And by searching I got `self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true`, by putting that code, It removes the Border but it also remove the shadow effect.

[image]

I need like following image:

[image]

No Border but shadow effect.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: try self.tabBar.layer.maskToBounds = true

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a `UIView` in your TabBar and make `.shadowImage` and `.backgroundImage` equal to `UIImage()`

**Code**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {

        let tabGradientView = UIView(frame: tabBarController.tabBar.bounds)
        tabGradientView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tabGradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;


        tabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(tabGradientView)
        tabBarController.tabBar.sendSubview(toBack: tabGradientView)
        tabGradientView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        tabGradientView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        tabGradientView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        tabGradientView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        tabGradientView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        tabBarController.tabBar.clipsToBounds = false
        tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: No, Its not working, tried before and now, I need Shadow effect and NO Border, like above 3rd Image. Thanks though for your concern.

Comment: can you post your current code adding this line? @AbhishekMitra I have this line working in a project and works

Comment: @AbhishekMitra check my updated answer and let me know

Comment: Very Thanks,  by changing values of `tabGradientView.alpha = 0.8`

`tabGradientView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0`

`tabGradientView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1`

I got my desired result.. :) Many many Thanks for your concern in my question..

Comment: @AbhishekMitra tabGradientView.alpha should be 1, if not you will have visual issues because of tabBar transparence

Comment: Thanks Again, I changed it.. :)

Comment: god bless, was looking for this solution for hours

Answer (score 22):

So the answer provided by @Reinier Melian didn't work for me, but I made a custom TabBar controller with this effect that worked:

**Updated for Swift 5, iOS 13, Xcode 11**

**Code:**

```
class MyCustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self

        //here's the code that creates no border, but has a shadow:

        tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = false
        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

**How to Use It:**

To use it, drag a tab bar controller on to the storyboard and then just change the class of that tab bar to this one via the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on iOS 12.1, Swift 4.2**

The `UITabBar` view added in your `.storyboard/.xib` file need to be lower (position in the `Document Outline`) than the content that will be scrolling, in my case the `Web Report Container` is the scrolling part and the `Tab Bar` is the UITabBar in the bottom. I put it as well lower in the Document Outline as you can see here to give it a lower z-index:

[image]

Then in your `ViewController.swift` file you could have a setup like this in your `viewDidLoad` for example:

```
// Remove default line
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

// Add only shadow 
tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 8
tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
```

You can play with `shadowOpacity` and `shadowRadius` to adjust the shadowing visual to the desired effect.